# How to make a html button take input of 2 textbox values from user and return it in another view on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My view here

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<center><h1 style="color:blue">Folder Comparer</h1></center>
<center><p class="lead" style="color:red ">Input both folder paths to compare</p></center>
<center><p><input size="22" id="Text1" type="text" /> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Compare</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <input id="Text1" type="text" /></p></center>
<select id="FolderA" multiple="multiple" class="list1">

    @foreach (var i in Model.FolderA)
    {
        <option class="option2">i.Name</option>
    }

</select>
```

Now i need these two text box to be used as values in another view.

Here is my controller

```
        public ActionResult Compare(string folder1, string folder2)
    {
        Managers.FolderComparer fc = new Managers.FolderComparer();
        var comparedFolders = fc.Compare(folder1, folder2);
        return View(comparedFolders);
    }
```

**My controller is calling a funciton that takes two string inputs**

Comment: Add `input type=submit` and form, then take an array of string which would be your selected options. Do whatever you want on server side and return view with result. And you know, `id` are not working, you should specify `name` for form being posted back.

Comment: Use a form with `FormMethod.Get`, and give your inputs a `name` attribute to match your parameters. But this will be far easier if you bind to a model using the strong typed `HtmlHelper` methods.

Answer (score 0):

sadly i haven't got enough reputation to add this as an comment but use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
```

{

```
 <input size="22" id="Text1" type="text" name= "folder1" />
a submit buttom
```

}
so the name = the parameter in the controller.